# how to show $\{f ≥ g\}$ measurable?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Show that if $f$ and $g$ are two (extended) measurable functions over $(X, σ(X), μ)$, then $\{z ∈ X : f(z) ≥ g(z)\}$ is measurable.

How to prove this since $f − g$ is not well-defined in general, could someone prove this in details?

Comment: The set where $f \ge g$ and both are finite is measurable by studying $f - g$. Now consider special cases of $f = \pm \infty$ and $g = \pm \infty$, and recall that, e.g., $\{z : f(z) = \infty\}$ is measurable (why?).

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Of course, there is no issue in the case where $g < \infty$.  It suffices to note, then, that
$$
\{f \geq g\} = \{f \geq g \text{ and } g < \infty\} \cup \{f = \infty\}
$$

Comment: The second set should probably by $\{f = g = \infty\}$.

Comment: @T.Bongers but $\infty - r$ is well-defined for $r < \infty$ (by the $\overline{\Bbb R}$ rules that I'm used to, anyway).

Comment: Right, but for $f \ge g$ we need $f = g$ there.

Comment: Could you prove in details?

Comment: @Did thanks for that!

Comment: @T.Bongers why do we need f=g rather than f=∞ and g is finite?